# conditional argument of a function to select rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sym': ['msft', 'amd', 'bac', 'citi'], 'close'`: [100, 30, 70, 80]})
```

And this is the simplified form of function that I want to use:

```
def add_volume(df):
  df['volume'] = [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000]
  return df
```

I want to pass an argument to this function that returns the rows that I want. For example: `def add_volume(df, sector = ['tech', 'bank'])`. And if I choose the `tech` `sector` the function returns this:

```
      sym  close  volume
  0  msft    100    1000  
  1   amd     30    2000
```

and on the `bank` `sector` it returns the other two rows.

EDIT: I want to call the function like this `add_volume(df, sector = 'tech')` and then it returns the first two rows

Comment: where is sector? is it `sym` in the example ?

Comment: I am not good at functions! just pass an argument that returns what I want. Feel free to edit my post :)

Comment: no I just wanted to pass an argument to my function.

Comment: Can you explain clearly?  How `['tech', 'bank']` is related to only first two rows?

Comment: I wanted to pass an argument. And inside the function by using conditionals the function returns what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amir... Coding is not magic. The code cannot just know what sector means in relation to the data.

If you want the words `"tech"`, `"sector"` and the like to be related to your data in some way, you need to include them in your df. Only then can you access them using your function.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sym': ['msft', 'amd', 'bac', 'citi'], 'close'`: [100, 30, 70, 80], 'sector': ['tech', 'tech', 'bank','bank']})

# Then you can do
def add_volume(df, sector):
    df['volume'] = [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000] 
    new_df = df[df['sector'].isin(sector)]
    return new_df

res = add_volume(df, sector = ['tech'])
```

```
    sym  close  volume
0  msft    100    1000  
1   amd     30    2000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below:

```
def add_volume(df,col,params):
    df['volume'] = [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000] #better to add this outside the function
    df=df[df[col].isin(params)]
    return df
add_volume(df,'sym',['msft','amd'])
```

---

```
    sym  close  volume
0  msft    100    1000
1   amd     30    2000
```

Comment: Is it possible to  call the function like this : `add_volume(df, sector = 'tech')`. And then it returns the first two rows

Comment: @Amir there is no 'sector' and 'tech' in the dataframe. How do we know which is which

Comment: If there is a column `sector` in the df, it is possible?

Comment: @Amir yes instead of `sym` pass `sector` and instead of `['msft','amd']` pass the list of original values which is in sector  to filter

Comment: ok thank you for your try too. I didn't explain it correctly :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass an optional argument, you can do this:

```py
def add_volume(df, sector=None):
    if sector is None:
        # do without the sector argument
    else
        # do with the sector argument
```

So know you can do both of these statements:

```py
df = df(add_volume)
df = df(add_volume, sector_list)
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this:-

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sym': ['msft', 'amd', 'bac', 'citi'], 'close': [100, 30, 70, 80], 
                  'sector': ['tech', 'tech', 'bank','bank']})
def add_volume(df, sector='tech'):
    df['volume'] = [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000] 
    df = df[ df['sector']==sector ] 
    return df

df= add_volume(df)  # By default sector is 'tech' AND we can pass 'bank' also.
df
```

I hope it may help you.